# Answer about how to use Adobe Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

i would like to know how to use photoshop

So answer me or i will get very angry indeed.
I am a very patient person and you are testing my patience to the very limits of existence.

Comment: [Click here for reasons why your question may have been down voted or placed on hold.](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2632/why-was-my-question-downvoted-and-or-closed). Your questions simply isn't reasonable to answer in this type of platform. There are plenty of other online resources available online for free.

Comment: Ahh... thanks for the laugh... needed that :)

Answer (score 1):

Double click the icon on your desktop or in your application directory!

Comment: First you need to install an operating system

Comment: @GiantCowFilms don't forget to build a computer, and run electrical wiring through your house!